# Call function php in comment in file html

Tags: php, html, function

I have a one file html format as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contanier">
            <!-- MAIN showdata('postdata') -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Function showdata is define in file main.php as follow:

```
function showdata($data){
      //code
}
```

I do not understand the mechanism of call from html. Can anyone explain for me ???.
Thank all !

Comment: google `php tutorial`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [embeding php in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877525/embeding-php-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is a php file, you can do:

```
<div class="contanier">
    <?php showdata('postdata') ?>
</div>
```